# Referencing a menu itemId in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu-items

I was wondering how i reference the menu Item i have created, in my switch?
Thank you in advance.

MY menu Item:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Vælg en handling");

        //I just want one of the menu items under referenced.
        menu.add(0,0,0, "Slet denne regning");
        menu.add(0,1,0, "Omdøb denne regning");

    }
```

And my Switch Case:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    adapter.getSelectedItem(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case //This is where i want one of my menu items referenced :
            finish();
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

It should also be noted that my switch is in my mainActivity, and my Menu item is   in another class(A Recycler adapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MenuItem mi;
```

The `add` method returns the menuitem:

`mi = menu.add(0,0,0, "Slet denne regning");`

and in `onContextItemSelected`:

```
if (item == mi) {
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: It seems too be right exept that i cannot resolve the symbol mi in my mainactivity

Comment: Declare it on top just before onCreate();

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: see my edited answer. The variable mi needs to be global in the activity.

Comment: My "mi = menu.add(0,0,0, "Slet denne regning");" is in another class, than MainActivity :P

Comment: What is this a popup menu or the activity's main menu?

Comment: Well it is a menu that popups from a recyclerView item. so i have created the menu itself in my recyclerView adapter, and then afterwards called the menu in my mainactivity to make it apear, wich also is where i give it actions.

Comment: Yeah but that might still be the problem, thank you for the help :) but i'll have to look at it toomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

In your menu.xml file you define an id for the item e.g. @+id/menu_item

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/item"
        android:title="Item"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Then in your switch, you add **R.id.menu_item**:

```
//...
switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item:
                doAction();
                break;
//...
```

Comment: I haven't got a xml file but i made the item directly with the id of "0" istead.

Comment: Like so " menu.add(0,0,0, "Slet denne regning");" this is the item i want refferenced :)

Comment: @Otto the second argument in your method is the Id, try using it case 0 would be for "Slet denne regning", case 1 for "Omdøb denne regning"

Comment: Okay ill try that too Thank you